# Definition of a $\sigma$ - finite set

Tags: measure-theory

I know the definition of a $\sigma$-finite measure. But I found a problem in which it asks to show a particular set is $\sigma$ finite? But what is a $\sigma$ finite set?

This is the problem I found. If $f∈L^+$ and $∫f<∞$, then show that $\{x:f(x)=∞\}$ is a null set and $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ is σ− finite.

Answer (score 10):

A set is called $\sigma$-finite, or is said to have $\sigma$-finite measure, if it is the countable union of sets of finite measure.

Comment: How is $\sigma$-finite measure defined?

Comment: Let $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ Where ${E_n}$ are mutually disjoint. If $\mu(E_n)<\infty$, then we call $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure.

Comment: @jgcello  These $E_{n}$ need not be mutually disjoint.

Comment: I think the sets in the countable union should be measurable sets..

Comment: @mathiu_lady yes, but to me this is implicit in "sets of finite measure" as to be of finite measure  they need to be measurable in the first place. But maybe that's not standard.